# Why moodle after installation is giving blank page on localhost:8080

Tags: php, moodle

I installed moodle on localhost with all the instructions given at that time. After installation, page is getting redirected to following url and blank page is shown.

URL: http://localhost:8080/moodle/user/editadvanced.php?id=2

[image: Error page afetr installation of moodle]

Comment: is your http server running?

Comment: Yes! My localhost server is running.

Comment: What server are you using, and on which OS?

Comment: Normally this happens due to a PHP version miss match. Which version of Moodle are you using? What is the PHP version installed in the server?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my problem after I upgraded my PHP version from  7.1.7 to 7.1.11 using moodle 3.4 version